# ObjectAnimator - Animating View that starts over actionbar and translates to the bottom of the layout

Tags: android, animation, android-animation, android-actionbar-compat, objectanimator

I would like to have a View and trigger an animation using translation that starts over the actionbar and moves down to my layout (per say in the bottom).

The View is not part of the actionbar (is not an actionItem).

What I've tried:

1- When I animate a view that is part of my layout it looks like it comes from the actionbar coords and then slides down BUT the view is being drawn below the actionbar (so it doesnt give the effect it comes on top from the actionbar)

2.- I created a new LinearLayout that holds to the view i want to animate and added it to DecorView to have the view on top of the actionbar, but when I perform the animation it starts animating smoothly over the actionbar but as soon as is out of the bound of the abc it just jumps directly to the end (x,y) of the animation so it doesnt give the translation effect).

3.- I'm able to animate ActionItems in the abc as well but is only within the constraints of the action bar so this is not an option.

The work I did was using setClipChildren(false) so I can translate everywhere.

Some code using hardcoded values for the sake of the question:

```
ObjectAnimator translateY = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    mPersonalizationProgressBar, 
                    "translationY", 
                    10,400);

ObjectAnimator translateX = ObjectAnimator.ofFloat(
                    mPersonalizationProgressBar, 
                    "translationX", 
                    10,400);
```

This is using ActionBarCompat from the support library.

- any ideas what's going and how can this be achieved will be appreciated!